# Laravel 5.1 - How to send parameter to authorize() function

Tags: php, laravel, request

I'm making a real estate application. When the user opens one of his published properties to edit, in the edit page, the form opens like this:

```
{!! Form::model($property, ['method'=>'PUT', 'route'=>['property.update', 'id'=>$property->id], 'files'=>true]) !!}
```

As you can see, in the 'route' array I'm sending the named route and the id of the property to be edited. But how do I access that $id in the Request Class?

```
class EditPropertyRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user owns this property and is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize($id)
    {
        return Property::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                       ->where('id', $id)
                       ->exists();
    }
}
```

The error I get is

> Missing argument 1 for
>   App\Http\Requests\EditPropertyRequest::authorize()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is from doc

```
public function authorize()
{
    $commentId = $this->route('comment');

    return Comment::where('id', $commentId)
                  ->where('user_id', Auth::id())->exists();
}
```

So `$this->route('comment');` is a URL parameter `Route::post('comment/{comment}');`

Comment: Ok, now I understand, you don't pass parameters but you use the route method. It worked perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
request('id')
```

You can use request();